# How to get notified when AVAudioPlayer loops back to the beginning?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm playing a sound file in a loop and need to restart an animation with it every time the loop starts from the beginning.

I couldn't find a delegate method for it in the documentation. Is there a way to get notified when the player loops around to the beginning?

My approach was to use a timer which checks current play time every few milliseconds but this sounds like a horrible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW13) for the avaudioplayer instance. Then the delegate will be notified whenever the sound has successfully finished playing. Then you can probably restart the player to play again and restart your animation. Just off the top of my head. Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068-CH1-SW5) for more information.

Comment: The AVAudioPlayer can loop automatically around without the delegate's help. It's a simple loop property. Haven't tried checking if the finishedplaying method gets called. I assume it does not because it still plays when looping.

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK your solution is the only one which works. The finishedPlaying method is not called whilst looping so sampling the position is the only technique.

I'm updating some inherited code to add looping and came to this conclusion under iOS8.